# Help with WPF UI

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I need to create a dynamic UI in WPF. Something like below,

```
  Date   Hyatt Regency  Ritz Carlton    Holiday Inn..
             16             10               5
 12/16      20%             12%             10%

            10              5                4
 12/17      2%              3%               1%
```

Now, my question is that as the entire UI is dynamic, the hotel names the numeric amount, I am not able to space them properly. So if the hotel name becomes long the records below do not align properly. Is there a way in WPF that I can create the XAML from code behind dynamically and still look perfect spacing wise.

Comment: Do you want all of the columns to be the same width, or do you want each to automatically fit the contents?

Comment: I want the Column Headers like Hotel names to automatically fit the contents but then I also want the numeric values to be aligned exactly in center to the Hotel name. The date field as well as all the numeric fields are dynamic.

Comment: Yes, you can. XamlReader.Parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after something like this:

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<List<String>> data = GetData();
        var grid = CreateGrid(data.Count, data.First().Count());
        PopulateGrid( grid, data );
        this.Content = grid;            
    }

    private void PopulateGrid(Grid grid, List<List<string>> data)
    {
        int rowNumber = 0;
        foreach (var rowContents in data)
        {
            int colNumber = 0;
            foreach (var colValue in rowContents)
            {
                var tb = new TextBlock { Text = colValue, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, Margin=new Thickness(5) };
                Grid.SetRow(tb, rowNumber);
                Grid.SetColumn(tb, colNumber);
                grid.Children.Add(tb);
                colNumber++;
            }
            rowNumber++;
        }
    }

    private List<List<string>> GetData()
    {
        return new List<List<String>>() 
        {
            new List<String>( ) { "Date",  "Hyatt Regency",  "Ritz Carlton", "Holiday Inn" },
            new List<String>( ) { "",  "16",  "10", "5" },
            new List<String>( ) { "12/16",  "20%",  "12%", "10%" },
            new List<String>( ) { "",  "",  "", "" },
            new List<String>( ) { "",  "10",  "5", "4" },
            new List<String>( ) { "12/17",  "2%",  "3%", "1%" },
        };
    }

    private Grid CreateGrid(int rows, int cols)
    {
        var grid = new Grid();

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        for (int c = 0; c < rows; c++)
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });

        return grid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?

If the inbuilt one doesn't do it for you, there are plenty of third party data grid controls:

[Telerik GridView](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/gridview.aspx)

[DevExpress DXGrid](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/)

And many more. If you look around, you can find free ones as well.

Comment: May I ask why? This is typical DataGrid use case. You would end up creating a grid-like control of your own anyways.

Comment: I think that will look confusing as the above is just the UI of one record. I will have to loop through the above UI for dynamic records so I think it wont look as appealing as without using a datagrid..

Comment: You can style the DataGrid, not every DataGrid must look like an Excel table. It is simply an UI control that can be easily bound to a 2D-like data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a regular old `Grid`:

Date
        Hyatt Regency
        Ritz-Carleton
        Holiday Inn

```
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">16</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">10</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right">5</TextBlock>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">12/16</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">20%</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">12%</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right">10%</TextBlock>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">10</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">5</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right">4</TextBlock>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">12/17</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">2%</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">3%</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right">1%</TextBlock>
  </Grid>
  <TextBlock/>
</DockPanel>
```

But if you're building something like this using code-behind, you're doing it wrong.  You should be using data templates and binding.  To do this, you'd actually create a separate grid for each block of data, and use shared size groups to keep the column widths in sync.  That's a somewhat bigger question, but one that you can address after you've got the layout right.